# Preprocessing with Javacc/ push front some chars in the stream?

Tags: java, javacc, preprocessor

Using **javacc** can I push some new characters in front of the inputstream ?

for example let's say that my parser parses the following syntax:

```
#define Paragraphs  "Paragraph+"
#define Volume "(Title,(Chapter,${Paragraphs})+)"

Book=${Volume}+;
```

How can I tell javacc that its scanner should preprocess `${Volume}` to `(Title,(Chapter,Paragraph+)+)` before invoking the parser ?

Can It be achieved using the **MORE** statement ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've found the solution: Some java statements can be added in the **TOKEN** section and the current buffer is defined in a StringBuilder named '**image**':

```
| <Y:"${"(<NAME)+ "}" >
        {
        String oldValue=image.toString();
        image.setLength(0);
        image.append(my_dict.get(oldValue));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Token.image` is a public field, so you could also just set it directly.  Here's an example in my JavaCC book's tokenizer chapter:

```
TOKEN : {
   {matchedToken.image = image.append("B").toString();}
}
```

You can download all the book's example source code [here](http://generatingparserswithjavacc.com/).